# Output a Multi-dimensional Array in twig from symfony controller

Tags: symfony, twig

So i have this array in my indexController

```
 $numbers = [
        'prime' => [2, 3, 5, 7, 11],
        'fibonacci' =>  [1, 1, 2, 3, 5],
        'triangular' => [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
    ];
```

And i tried outputing it in the render function like this

```
'primes' => $numbers['prime']
```

and like this

```
$primes = $numbers['prime'];
'primes' => $primes
```

and in my index.html.twig i just have this simple call

```
    {{ primes }}
```

Exception

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion").

Comment: you should use tags like `{%for%}` to show the array elements. if you have many arrays you can write a filter for their representing .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to print that array? You must use a bucle for that.

```
{% for item in primes %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I may have over complicated things, yes this work. Thank you.